# C++ error: 'No suitable conversion from [class name] to "int" '

Tags: c++, class

I'm working on a class for the addition, subtraction and multiplication of polynomials.

I'm getting the following errors:

'No suitable conversion function from [class name] to "int" '

in statements:

```
return c;    (addition function)

return deriv;
```

Can anyone offer any guidance on how to correct these?

Thanks very much in advance,
Ryan

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Poly
{
private:

//  int ord;                            // the order of the polynomial
//  int coeff[100];

public:

    int ord;                            // the order of the polynomial
    int coeff[100];


    int a, b, c;
    Poly();                             // constructor
    int addition(int);                  // adds 2 polynomials
    int subtraction(int);               // subtracts 2 polynomials
    int multiplication(int);            // multiplies 2 polynomials
    void evaluate(int);                 // uses Horner's method to compute and return the polynomial evaluated at x
    int differentiate(int);         // 
    void set(int, int);                 // mutator function
    int order();
    void print();                       // prints the results
};

Poly::Poly()            // the default constructor
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        coeff[i] = 0;
    }
}

void Poly::set(int a, int b)    // mutator function
{
    // coeff = new Poly[b + 1];
    coeff[b] = a;
    ord = order();
}

int Poly::order()
{
    int d = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        if (coeff[i] != 0) d = i;
        return d;
}

void print()
{
    int coeff[] = { 0 };

    for (int i = 99; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (coeff[i] != 0)
        {
            cout << coeff[i] << "x^" << i << " ";
        }
    }
}

int evaluate(int x)
{
    int p = 0;
    for (int i = ord; i >= 0; i--)
        p = coeff[i] + (x * p);
    return p;
}

int Poly::differentiate(int)
{
    if (ord == 0)
    {
        Poly t;
        t.set(0, 0);
        return t;
    }

    Poly deriv;
    deriv.ord = ord - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < ord; i++)
        deriv.coeff[i] = (i + 1) * coeff[i + 1];
    return deriv;
}

int Poly::addition(Poly b)
{
    Poly a = *this;
    Poly c;

    for (int i = 0; i <= a.ord; i++)
        c.coeff[i] += a.coeff[i];
    for (int i = 0; i <= b.ord; i++)
        c.coeff[i] += b.coeff[i];

    c.ord = c.order();

    return c;
}

Poly subtraction(Poly b)
{
    Poly a = *this;
    Poly c;

    for (int i = 0; i <= a.ord; i++)
        c.coeff[i] += a.coeff[i];
    for (int i = 0; i <= b.ord; i++)
        c.coeff[i] -= b.coeff[i];

    c.ord = c.order();

    return c;
}

int Poly::multiplication(Poly b)
{
    Poly a = *this;
    Poly c;

    for (int i = 0; i <= a.ord; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j <= b.ord; j++)
        c.coeff[i + j] += (a.coeff[i] * b.coeff[j]);
    c.order = c.order();
}

int main()
{
    Poly a, b, c, d;
    a.set(7, 4);                //  7x^4
    a.set(1, 2);                //   x^2

    b.set(6, 3);                //   6x^3
    b.set(-3, 2);               //  -3x^2

    c = a.subtraction(b);       // (7x^4 + x^2) - (6x^3 - 3x^2)

    c.print();

    cout << "\n";

    d = c.differentiate().differentiate();

    d.print();

    cout << "\n";

    cout << c.evaluate(2);  // substitute x with 2
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's exactly as it sounds. You can't implicitly convert a `Poly` to an `int`. For both of those errors, you are trying to return a `Poly` from a function declared as returning an `int`.

Comment: @ Jashaszun - thanks!  But, *WHERE* is that happening (I'm brand new to C++)?

Comment: Why do some of your operations return `int` and others `Poly`?

Comment: Furthermore, your class declaration is completely inconsistent with your member function definitions, e.g. `int addition(int);` versus `int Poly::addition(Poly b)` - both of these should probably be: `Poly Poly::addition(Poly b)`

Comment: @user3407254 It's happening on those two lines, as you said...

Comment: Your constructor doesn't need a loop. `std::fill` already does that operation. However, since it's a constructor, use the constructor initializer list (`: coeff{}`). `order()` could just use `std::find_if_not` to find the first non-zero and then `std::iota` to fill the rest. `print` goes out of bounds on the local array (which I doubt is supposed to be there). Some of these would be taken care of better by just using a vector and not limiting yourself to order 100.

Comment: this happened to me with a struct when I had declared it in the wrong place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your (first) problem is in this function:

```
int Poly::addition(Poly b)
{
    Poly a = *this;
    Poly c;

    for (int i = 0; i <= a.ord; i++)
        c.coeff[i] += a.coeff[i];
    for (int i = 0; i <= b.ord; i++)
        c.coeff[i] += b.coeff[i];

    c.ord = c.order();

    return c;
}
```

You say you will return an int:

```
int Poly::addition(Poly b)
//^------ promise to return int
```

but you return `c` where `c` is a `Poly`. change the return type:

```
Poly Poly::addition(Poly b)
```

`int Poly::differentiate(int)` has the same problem.
Change it to

```
Poly Poly::differentiate(int)
```

BTW - Why does this take a `int` which it ignores?

Furthermore, `int Poly::multiplication(Poly b)` doesn't return anything as it stands.

You have further problems. For example the print and evaluate functions should be member functions and it may make more sense to use a std::vector to store the coefficients.

The compiler probably told you the line number of the error if you look closely.

Comment: And there is a similar problem with `multiplication()`: it should also return a `Poly` instead of an `int`, and by the way, it should `return c` (for the moment its return is missing).

Comment: It should return something :-) I suspect there are even more problems lurking but that's a lot of code.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is telling you the exact problem. 
Your addition method is declared to return an `int` while your var `c` is an instance of class `Poly`.
You need to return an `int`.

Comment: What about the `differentiate` function?

Comment: More likely he needs to change the function return type to `Poly`.

Comment: @Jashaszun same problem there too.

Comment: @Jude Pereira - thank you.  *HOW* do I correct this (I'm brand new to C++)?

Comment: You'd declare your method like this
`Poly Poly::addition(Poly b)`

Comment: @user3407254 You correct this in one of two ways: (1) by returning an `int`. For example, in your `addition` method, instead of `return c;` you could `return c.ord;` (or whatever else you want, as long as it's an `int`). (2) You declare your method to return a `Poly` instead of an `int`.